# First word of a phrase is dropped when I try and put it in a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Sorry for the vague header. Difficult to describe. I am trying to get a phrase from the user and put that phrase into a vector, word by word, separated by spaces. For some reason when the vector is printed it completely leaves out the first word of the phrase, if that makes sense. Here's the code I have so far:

```
 void printVector(vector<string>& words){

  cout << "Print words: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
      if (i < words.size()){
        cout << words[i] << ", ";
      }
      else
        cout << words[i];
      }
 cout << endl;
}


int main(){

  string phraseInput;
  string stop = "done";
   do{
     cin >> phraseInput;

      if(phraseInput == stop){
        cout << "Program finished." << endl;
        return 0;
      }
      else {
        getline(cin, phraseInput);

        istringstream iss(phraseInput);

        vector<string> words;
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             back_inserter(words));

         printVector(words);
     }

  }while(phraseInput != stop); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have sample input, current output, and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have taken input for two times only first one skipped
Now you should change this

```
     else{ string temp;

            getline(cin, temp);
            phraseInput+=temp;
            istringstream iss(phraseInput);
//.....
```

Comment: This solution from my first outlook and as expected. you can edit for further problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your answer

I tested your code with the phrase "this is line."

Your variable "phraseInput" first take "this" string.

[image]

After getline(cin, phraseInput) line.

Your variable "phraseInput" take "is line" string.

[image]

Therefore when it prints, it simply skips the first keyword.

Result is: the first string "this" is missing

[image]

I think in this way: You take two input from user.

Therefore I thought " What happens if I commented first cin? "

[image]

After commented on your first cin. I got all the string in variable "phraseInput"

[image]

Result is:

[image]

Then I thought "do while" loop also unnecessary, since it prints any word it took from user.

I also commented your "do while" loop

Here is the final version of your code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void printVector(vector<string>& words){

    cout << "Print words: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
        if (i < words.size()){
            cout << words[i] << ", ";
        }
        else
            cout << words[i];
    }
       cout << endl;
}


int main(){

    string phraseInput;
    string stop = "done";
    /*do{
        cin >> phraseInput;

        if (phraseInput == stop){
            cout << "Program finished." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {*/
            getline(cin, phraseInput);

            istringstream iss(phraseInput);

            vector<string> words;
            copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
                 istream_iterator<string>(),
                 back_inserter(words));

            printVector(words);
      //}

            system("pause");
      //} while (phraseInput != stop);
}
```